# How to set KeepAlive property on the SignalR ConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net, web-config, signalr

I found this link about setting KeepAlive property on the ConfigurationManager for SignalR:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/168

The problem is that I am having difficulty to understand where exactly this should be set. Should I set the ConfigurationManager in webconfig or is there an option to do this in code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can set in global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   SignalR.GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
}
```

See https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Configuring-SignalR